# Shishken mesh in numerical methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm already read a document about : numerical solution for singularly perturbed problems, and the most documents use the shishken mesh for the descrtisation  of the problems.
my question is : why we don't use uniform mesh for this type of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for singularly perturbed problems, the main issue is the presence of layers, whether be in boundary or interior. The resolution of the grid near these layers is not easy, one requires a fine mesh near them. If we use an uniform refinement then our DOFs (or unknowns) increase a lot and hence the computation time is affected. To resolve this issue, we use special meshes where we refine only where we have the layers. This helps to solve the problem as well as reduce the computation time.

Comment: thanks for the answers, well if we result the problem numerically with galerkin method but we change the basis of the polynomial (we don't use lagrange basis) and use uniform mesh, we have a problem in layer also or no ?

Comment: Yes, we can. Then the idea of stabilized Finite Element comes. If we use Petrov Galerkin methods (read SUPG), then we can use Uniform meshes. I would suggest going through the book of Roos, Stynes, and Tobiska for more details

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I'm very interested about this topic.